# jQuery.attr function

Tags: jquery

i am using

```
$('<div/>').attr('font-weight','bold');
```

It is not applying font-weight to bold with above function. Is there something wrong in there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yea, something's wrong, the $() function is used to select an element, class or id, not a mal-formed tag. Also, you should use the css() function to change css properties so you need something like this:

```
$("#mydiv").css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

If you want to select *all* divs, you can do this:

```
$("div").css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Answer (score 3):

@cloudhead has answered this well, but if you want to alter multiple css properties at one time it would look like:

```
$("div").css({'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': '3em'});
```

Alternately, you could use jQuery's chaining method. Not as efficient, but it's a nice taste of the kind of flexibility jQuery has.

```
$("div").css('font-weight', 'bold').css('font-size', '3em');
```

I encourage you to look at the [jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) to get a better sense of what jQuery can do.

Comment: There is a syntax problem with your first example.  You need to have a colon between key / value, not a comma.